# Does this kind of function exist?

Tags: limits, functions

Does a function, $f(x)$, exist such that for some integer $a$, $f(a) = 1$. In addition, the function evaluated at all integers between $1$ and $a$ is $0$. Finally, the limit of this function as $x$ approaches infinity is $1$. Thanks!

Comment: Piecewise functions?

Comment: Try tweaking trig functions like $ y= 2 + \cos \pi x $

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\cases{0&if $x<a$\cr 1&if $x\ge a$.\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are many functions like that. 
You have already described the function $f(x)$ over all the input values
$1 < x \leq a.$ 
We also know that the function is discontinuous at $x = a.$
(This is implied by the values you've already required it to have.)

Regarding the parts of the function you have not already explicitly specified,
for $x > a$ you can take any function whose limit is $1$ as
$x \to \infty,$ and for $x \leq 1$ you can use any function you want.